# AWS EKS with ALB: remoteEntry.js returns HTML instead of expected JavaScript

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, micro-frontend

I have deployed a microfrontend architecture on AWS EKS and am using the ELB Ingress Controller for routing. My application works perfectly when accessed locally, but I'm facing an issue when trying to access it on the deployed environment.

The problem is with my remoteEntry.js file. When accessed directly, instead of returning the expected JavaScript content, it returns an HTML response.

Setup:

1. The application is containerized using Docker. It's deployed on AWS
2. EKS, and routing is handled by the ELB Ingress Controller.
3. I've configured an Ingress resource to handle routing.
4. The application is using NGINX for serving content.

Issue:

- When accessing https://[host-url]/qes-run/remoteEntry.js, the response is:

```html
<html><head><title>HostName</title><script defer="defer" src="main.34c9b82be2435d13fa03.js"></script></head><body><div id="root"></div></body></html>
```

- However, when I shell into the pod and navigate to the location of remoteEntry.js, it is present and contains the correct JavaScript content.

What I've tried:

1. Verified the NGINX configuration to ensure correct routing for
   static files.
2. Checked Ingress configuration to ensure the paths and backend services are correctly set.
3. Inspected the ELB on AWS to ensure listeners and rules are correctly configured.
4. Checked that all registered targets in the target groups are healthy.

Despite the above checks, the problem persists.What could be causing this behavior, and how can I ensure that the correct JavaScript content is served instead of the HTML response?

Ingress Configuration for Microfrontend:

```js
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: >-
      arn:aws:acm:eu-central-1:xxxx-xxxx
  name: qes-run
spec:
  rules:
    - host: hostdns.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: qes-run
                port:
                  number: 443
```

Ingress Configuration for Host:

```js
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: >-
  arn:aws:acm:eu-central-1:xxxx-xxxx
  name: qmc-ui
spec:
  rules:
- host: hostname.com
  http:
    paths:
      - path: /qes-run/
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: qes-run
            port:
              number: 443
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: qmc-ui
            port:
              number: 443
```

NGINX Configuration Microfrontend:

```js
server {
  listen 3000;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
      index index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

      # Add CORS headers
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS'; # Allowed methods
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range'; # Allowed headers
      add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range'; # Exposed headers
  }

  location = /remoteEntry.js {
      alias /usr/share/nginx/html/remoteEntry.js;
  }

  location @index {
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    expires 0;
    try_files /index.html =404;

    # Add CORS headers
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS'; # Allowed methods
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range'; # Allowed headers
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range'; # Exposed headers
  }
}
```

NGINX Configuration Host:

```html
server {
  listen 3000;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

    # Add CORS headers
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';  # Allowed methods
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';  # Allowed headers
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';  # Exposed headers
  }

  location @index {
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    expires 0;
    try_files /index.html =404;

    # Add CORS headers
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';  # Allowed methods
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';  # Allowed headers
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';  # Exposed headers
  }

  location /authentication/ {
    index silent.html signInPopup.html signOutPopup.html;
  }

  access_log false;
}
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please post the headers it returns along with the HTML?